# Cache cleaning not entering the function

Tags: html, caching, web

I am trying to clean my cache in a web application, so, I erase my CSS and put this function in my all.js archive, below document.ready:

```
// Check if a new cache is available on page load.
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
console.log("entered the function");
  window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
    console.log("entered the function 2");
    if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
      // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
      // Swap it in and reload the page to get the new hotness.
      window.applicationCache.swapCache();
      if (confirm('A new version of this site is available. Load it?')) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    } else {
      // Manifest didn't changed. Nothing new to server.
    }
  }, false);

}, false);
```

The problem is, it doesn't clean my cache, after erase my CSS it still shows the old one, and the `console.log("entered the function 2")` is not printing as well.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem doing:

```
// Check if a new cache is available on page load.
window.addEventListener('beforeload', function(e) {     

   if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
      // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
      // Swap it in and reload the page to get the new hotness.
 
      window.applicationCache.swapCache();
      window.location.reload();
   }
     
}, false);
```

I don't think is the right way, but it works.